# AngularJS filter and display range of dates using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

new to AngularJS- or the whole web development scene,

I am not even sure if this is possible or I am taking the most efficient path but I'm currently in need of a way to filter the range of dates using two input boxes, I'm using a jquery datepicker to always format the date to be "YYYY-MM-DD".

So, I have the following two input boxes,

```
<label class="" for="DateFromFilter">
          Date From:
</label>
 <input date-picker type="text" id="DateFromFilter" 
    class="form-control" 
    title="Please enter in YYYY-MM-DD format."
    ng-model="search.dueDate" />

 <label class="" for="DateToFilter">
           Date To:
 </label>
  <input date-picker type="text" id="DateToFilter" 
     class="form-control"
     title="Please enter in YYYY-MM-DD format."
     ng-model="search.toDate" />
```

And of course I have a table with a ng-repeat directive, getting its data from a local JSON file...only the dueDate is received.

```
<tr> ng-repeat="dateItem in dateItems | filter:search:strict | filter:dateFilter" 
<td>{{dateItem.dueDate}}</td></tr>
```

I need a way to let's say,

- if the user selects a date on the dueDate field ONLY, the ng-repeat
  list will filter and list all the dates FROM that date and onwards.
- if the user selects a date on the toDate field ONLY, the ng-repeat
  list will filter and list all the dates UP TO and including that
  certain date.
- if the user selects dates on both fields, the list will display all
  the dates between those two dates.

I'm so lost on which route to take, I've been thinking I have to write a custom filter function and compare the dates with if statements and so on but I don't have a decent enough of a code to illustrate here...

any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

---------------------------------------------UPDATE-------------------------------

So I ended up trying to write a custom filter function to the best of my abilities..it does not work though....;(   It kinda works if I take out the bolded conditional statements...

```
$scope.dateFilter = function (item) {

  /*
   * When the display starts, the inputs are undefined. also need to
   * account for when the inputs are empty to return everything.
   */
if ((!angular.isUndefined($scope.dueDate) && $scope.dueDate != "" ) **&&
      (angular.isUndefined($scope.toDate) || $scope.toDate == "" )**)
  {          
    var inputDate = new Date($scope.dueDate);
    var incomingDate = new Date(item.dueDate);
    if (inputDate <= incomingDate) 
    {
     return true;
    }
    else
    {
     return false;
    }
  }
else if ((!angular.isUndefined($scope.toDate) && $scope.toDate != "")**&&
          (angular.isUndefined($scope.dueDate) || $scope.dueDate == "" )**)
  {
    var inputDate = new Date($scope.toDate);
    var incomingDate = new Date(item.dueDate);
    if (inputDate >= incomingDate)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
else if ((!angular.isUndefined($scope.dueDate) && $scope.dueDate != "" )&&
          (!angular.isUndefined($scope.toDate) && $scope.toDate != ""))
  {
    var inputDueDate = new Date($scope.dueDate);
    var inputToDate = new Date($scope.toDate);
    if (inputDueDate < item.dueDate && inputToDate > item.dueDate )
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
     return false;
    }
  }
else
  {
   return true;
  }      
};
```

Comment: Why jQuery instead of Angular's date filter? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date

Comment: I thought the datepicker interface would be more friendly and allows the user to just click and it auto populates the date...and i thought Angular's date filter was just for formatting? is there a similar date picker widget?

Comment: Oh, I see. The posted answer has a helpful link about that.

Comment: Did you ever solve this, I'm struggling like crazy

Comment: Man i could easily write this from scratch with javascript, but when it come to angular i dont have a clue at all. I am trying solve this too

Answer (score 4):

Are you familiar with angular bootstrap UI?
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

There is an extension that might be what you are looking for here: http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

Instead of using a repeated list of dates you could use a date picker to display the available dates. As I think it might be easier to implament.

Edit:

Otherwise you could write a date range filter to handle this functionality. This might be a good place to start 
https://gist.github.com/Voles/5459410

useage: ng-repeat="... | daterage:start:end"

I am on my phone so am unable to give you an implementation at this time. Another user may be able to oblige.

Comment: Hey Matthew- I actually also have tried the bootstrap datepicker before, my issue is not with inputting the dates but filtering and displaying those range of dates with angular's ng-repeat directive...unless I'm missing something from your suggestion

Comment: My suggestion was to show available dates on the date picker, rather than a list of dates. You could have it set up more like a date display.

Comment: I see...I cannot use the date picker to show available dates...I have a table list with other data than just the dates which I must filter and display to the user in list view :(

Comment: Ok updated with an example filter I found elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

---

***Custom filter used to display dates between the selected dates from json or array***

---

```js
 var app = angular.module("myApp",[])
 .directive("datepicker1",function(){
  return{
   restrict:"A",
   link:function(scope,el,attr){
    el.datepicker({
     dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
    });
   }
  };
 })
 .directive("datepicker2",function(){
  return{
   restrict:"A",
   link:function(scope,el,attr){
    el.datepicker({
     dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
    });
   }
  };
 })
 .filter('myFilter',function(){
  return function(items, fromdate,todate){
   var arrayReturn = [];
   items.forEach(function(val,i){
    var a = new Date(items[i].cdet.cdate.date);
    console.log(a)
    console.log(fromdate)
    //var yy = a.getFullYear();
    //var mm = a.getMonth()+1;
    //var dd = a.getDate();
    var myDate = a;
    var fr = new Date(fromdate);
    var to = new Date(todate);
    if(myDate >= fr && myDate <= to){
     arrayReturn.push(items[i]);
    }
   });
   return arrayReturn;
  }
 })
 .controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.startdate = "2017-10-18";
  $scope.enddate = "2019-1-28"
  $scope.names = [
   {
    "cname" : "A",
    "cdet":{
     cdate:{
      date:"2018-5-15"
     }
    }
   },
   {
    "cname" : "B",
    "cdet":{
     cdate:{
      date:"2017-5-20"
     }
    }
   },
   {
    "cname" : "C",
    "cdet":{
     cdate:{
      date:"2019-5-13"
     }
    }
   },
   {
    "cname" : "D",
    "cdet":{
     cdate:{
      date:"2018-10-2"
     }
    }
   },
   {
    "cname" : "E",
    "cdet":{
     cdate:{
      date:"2018-12-8"
     }
    }
   }   
  ];
 });
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
 From Date:<input type="text" datepicker1 ng-model="startdate"/>
 To Date:<input type="text" datepicker2 ng-model="enddate"/>
 <ul ng-repeat="name in names | myFilter:startdate:enddate">
  <li><span>{{ name.cname }}</span> | <span>{{ name.cdet.cdate.date }}</span></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```